# Configuration Error while Jenkins-integration with Google-Cloud-build

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I am new to Jenkins-integration with Google-Cloud-build and struggling with setup of Jenkins(hosted in instance in gcloud)-jobs for different google-cloud projects using cloudbuild.yaml. I am using simple (also tried many ways) inline-yaml but getting (various) errors. I am not sure, how should I configure this. I searched over google for some help but seems no-one has posted anything related to my issue.

Jenkins-job output-
Google Cloud Build is being executed!
steps:

```
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml', '/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/amar-test-yaml/Dockerfile']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml']
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amar-test-yaml'
Project ID: yyyyyyy
Operation: {"metadata":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOperationMetadata","build":{"id":"99dde488-c68a-420a-b7fd-9c604dc0ce6c","status":"QUEUED","createTime":"2021-02-09T12:18:58.139821817Z","steps":[{"name":"gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker","args":["build","-t","gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml","/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/amar-test-yaml/Dockerfile"]},{"name":"gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker","args":["push","gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml"]}],"timeout":"600s","images":["gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml"],"projectId":"yyyyyyy","logsBucket":"gs://00000000000.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com","options":{"logging":"LEGACY"},"logUrl":"https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/99dde488-c68a-420a-b7fd-9c604dc0ce6c?project=950788658769","artifacts":{"images":["gcr.io/yyyyyyy/amar-test-yaml"]},"queueTtl":"3600s","name":"projects/000000000000000/locations/global/builds/99dde488-c68a-420a-b7fd-9c604dc0ce6c"}},"name":"operations/build/yyyyyyy/OTlkZGU0ODgtYzY4YS00MjBhLWI3ZmQtOWM2MDRkYzBjZTZj"}
Checking build status: QUEUED
Checking build status: WORKING
Checking build status: WORKING
Checking build status: FAILURE
Cloud Build failed. Status: FAILURE
 -> null
Log URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/99dde488-c68a-420a-b7fd-9c604dc0ce6c?project=00000000000
ERROR: Cloud Build failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Below is the output of google-cloud-build log

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: path "/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/amar-test-yaml/Dockerfile" not found
```

Comment: I have also tried below,                                                                                                   
 steps:
 # Build the container image
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/docuroute/amar-test-yaml', '.']
 images:
 - 'gcr.io/docuroute/amar-test-yaml'

Comment: Could you try using relative paths? Like for example, `./bitnami/jenkins/…` if you use an absolute path, like `/bitnami/jenkins/` you are working outside the workspace that Cloud Build generally uses.